# Duplicate some html then wrap it and insert multiple times

Tags: jquery, html

I got two divs with some inputs. Those divs placed in a row.
I have a button "+". When I click on the button I want to duplicate this row multiple times.

What I've tried:

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        var asSelect = $('div[data-type="affected-software"]').clone(),
            srSelect = $('div[data-type="severity-rating"]').clone().addClass('end');

        $('#addASRow').click(function() {
            var row = $('<div class="row">')
                .append(asSelect)
                .append(srSelect)
                .append('</div>');
            $('#asList').append(row);
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

So I'm cloning the divs then I wrap them into div.row (because first line of inputs also contains "+" button. Actually on first line I have 3 divs: 2 with inputs and 1 button. After clicking I only want to duplicate first 2 divs and place them in a row). And after that appending to the main #asList div.

What's happening: first time it works, then I got empty rows

Comment: have you tried using $('#addASRow').on("click", function() {}); ?

Comment: remove `.append('</div>')` and change `$('<div class="row">')` to `$('<div class="row"/>')` I'm really sure that you have a broken DOM, double check it

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved it with this code, though I don't think it's a clean solution:

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        var asSelect = $('div[data-type="affected-software"]').clone()[0].outerHTML,
            srSelect = $('div[data-type="severity-rating"]').clone().addClass('end')[0].outerHTML;

        $('#addASRow').click(function() {
            var row = $('<div class="row" />')
                .append(asSelect)
                .append(srSelect);
            $('#asList').append(row);
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```